# "reflect" vs "reflection on" or "reflection of"

Tags: phrase-usage, vocabulary, verbs

> The bride's elegant dress **reflected** her good taste.
>
> The bride's elegant dress **is a reflection on** her good taste.
>
> The bride's elegant dress **is a reflection of** her good taste.

Would you tell me if they mean the same thing?

If they would mean the same thing, what about the following question--link--? or I mean how could we distinguish such a distinction between these functions?

Similarly, what about these:

> A student's grades reflected her teacher
>
> A student's grades are a reflection **on** her teacher
>
> A student's grade are a reflection **of** her teacher

When, where or in which situation don't they mean the same? How can we distinguish such a distinction?

Comment: It looks easy but has great subtlety. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

> The bride's elegant dress reflected her good taste.

Here, we can see her good taste in her choice of dress. Her good taste is *the cause* of her choice of dress. Because she has good taste, she chose this dress.

> The bride's elegant dress is a reflection on her good taste.

Here, her good taste gets augmented by her choice of dress. Her good taste is a *result* of her choice of dress. Because she chose this dress, she has good taste. This does actually seem a strange thing to say.

> The bride's elegant dress is a reflection of her good taste.

This is a perfectly fine was to express the first sentence. Again, the good taste is the *cause* of her choice of dress.

> A student's grades reflected her teacher.

Because the grades are good, we know her teacher is good -> the teacher caused the good grades.

> A student's grades are a reflection on her teacher.

Because the grades are good, we think of the teacher as a good teacher -> the grades caused the teacher to look good.

> A student's grade are a reflection of her teacher.

Again, the same meaning as the first option -> because the teacher is good, the grades are good.

*A is a refection **of** B* means that we can explain that A is something (good or bad) *because* of B. *A reflects B* means the same thing.

*A is a reflection **on** B* means that because A is something (good or bad), B will appear to also be that (good or bad).

Answer (score 1):

> The bride's elegant dress reflected her good taste.
>
> The bride's {some adjective} dress is a reflection on her <del>good</del>
>   taste.
>
> The bride's elegant dress is a reflection of her good taste.

In the second sentence, I would not include "good".  The idiom "is a reflection on" normally implies at least the potential for a negative association.  For example, if one substitutes "gaudy" as the adjective. But usually the reflection is on a third party.

**Your (drunken) behavior, deputy, is a reflection on me, the sheriff of Dodge.**

**Students, your behavior is a reflection on this school. At the game this Saturday, I expect there to be no fighting or name-calling.**

**The mass exodus of American city-dwellers into the suburbs in the 1950s was *a reflection of* the growing popularity of the family automobile.  The traffic congestion on suburban roads today is *a poor reflection on* the regional planners who were responsible for striking a balance between highways and alternative forms of public transportation, such as street-cars and regional rail systems: most of the public funding went towards the building of new roads.**

Comment: So, considering all that you have taught me, I think  we could use them interchangeably, couldn't we?

Comment: I would not use them interchangeably. There is a nuanced difference between "reflection on" and "reflection of". I would use "is a reflection on" in contexts of censure or warning or criticism (including self-criticism), i.e. with behavior that may redound, or has redounded, to the *discredit* of the party delivering the warning or the censure or the criticism. "Reflection on her good taste" is not idiomatic. `Your not understanding this nuanced difference is a reflection on me: my explanation was not clear enough.`

Comment: thanks. But, what does"Reflection on her good taste" is not idiomatic imply?

Comment: "not idiomatic" means native speakers would not say it in that way. A native speaker would say "reflection `of` her good taste".  Both locutions (reflection of, reflection on) have to do with causality.  Her good taste caused her to buy that dress. But "reflection on" is a particular  kind of causality, that is, blame. Her bad taste caused her to wear a party dress to a funeral.  The party dress was a reflection `on` her taste.

Comment: You can also think of the distinction between `reflection of` and `reflection on` as the differences between `responsibility` and `blame`.  Something or someone can be responsible for good outcomes and bad outcomes.  But something or someone can be to blame only for bad outcomes.  Her good taste `was responsible for` her choice of a suitable dress. The suitable dress `was a reflection of` her good taste. Her bad taste `was to blame for` her wearing a party dress to a funeral; the party dress `was a reflection on` her taste.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally take "reflection on" as "somebody's thoughts on/about something" and "reflection of" as a structure implying something is a symptom of something else.