# reflect vs. reflect of/on

Tags: phrase-usage

A student's grades reflected his/her teacher

A student's grades are a reflection on his/ her teacher

A student's grade are a reflection of his/ her teacher

Could anyone possibly tell me if these mean the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does this differ from [your other question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33670/reflection-on-reflection-of-or-reflect)?